# how does the process of reading a com port barcode work here?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I have a barcodescanner hooked up to a serialport. I read the Serialport via DataReceived-Event

Now there is some weird timing issue occurring on repetitive scans that I try to explain in the following. So can you explain to me what is causing this difference?

I use this barcode: 01513511220001.

I scan it twice with both examples

Example1:

```
    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP1.DataReceived
        If SP1.BytesToRead > 0 Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) '!!!
            Dim str As String = SP1.ReadExisting
            Debug.WriteLine(str)
        End If
    End Sub
'Output Scan 1:
'01513511220001
'Output Scan 2!!!:
'01513511220001
```

Example2:

```
    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP1.DataReceived
        If SP1.BytesToRead > 0 Then
            Dim str As String = SP1.ReadExisting
            Debug.WriteLine(str)
        End If
    End Sub
'Output Scan 1:
'01513511220001
'Output Scan 2!!!:
'015135112
'20001
```

Note sometimes it cuts after the 9th digit sometimes it cuts after the 8th digit.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold?view=netframework-4.8) states: _Gets or sets the number of bytes in the internal input buffer before a DataReceived event occurs._ and [SerialPort.NewLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=netframework-4.8) states: _Gets or sets the value used to interpret the end of a call to the ReadLine() and WriteLine(String) methods_. I recommend reading all of the documentation for SerialPort.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding `ReadExisting`

You are using the `ReadExisting` function, which as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

> **Reads all immediately available bytes**, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

As it says it immediately reads and gives you the data, even though it's not fully complete. A barcode scanner does not know how long the code is so it continuously reads it, it is up-to the software to make sense of it.

### Understanding `DataReceived`

Similarly `DataReceived` method is called anytime there is data received via the port as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) (regardless of partial or full data, which depends on barcode scanner, internal buffers, etc.)

> Indicates that data has been received through a port represented by the SerialPort object.

Again it is upto the software to make sense of the data being received.

### Understanding your examples

The reason why your example 1 always works is because you add a delay before reading the actual data, giving a chance for the internal buffers to be full and hence you captured the full data upon calling `ReadExisting`

**Note: If you have to add a delay to the code, it's always the wrong way to do it (extreme exceptions exist, but this isn't it)**

### Possible Solutions

1. I would suggest using `ReadLine` method but it has its challenges
2. Simply put a logic to wait till all 14 characters are read before moving to next step of processing (given you have a fixed size code, even not this can still be done but logic becomes more complex).

### Crude Example for Solution 2

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP1.DataReceived
        If SP1.BytesToRead >= 14 Then 'Basically wait for the bytes to fill upto the length of the code
            Dim str As String = SP1.ReadExisting
            Debug.WriteLine(str)
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Note: I have not ran the above example, it's just indicative to what needs to be done**

### Specifically for Honeywell 1911i

As per its [manual](http://cdn.cnetcontent.com/55/e4/55e4041c-ff64-42a5-8a23-c4d92208d5c2.pdf), you need to ensure the **Programming Interface** for the device is set to **RS232 Serial Port** to do this refer to page 2-1 (page 27) of the manual under the heading *Programing the Interface* > *RS232 Serial Port*.

In this interface it automatically adds the suffix of Carriage Return and Line Feed, basically the NewLine character. Excerpt from the manual

> The **RS232 Interface** bar code is used when connecting to the serial port of a PC or terminal. The following **RS232 Interface** bar code also programs a carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) suffix, baud rate, and data format as indicated below. It also changes the trigger mode to manual.

This should allow you to use the `ReadLine` method to fetch the barcode without complexity.

*You can set this interface by simply scanning the RS232 Interface Bar Code from the manual.*

Comment: thank you i think i understood the problem. I do not know the length of a barcode in any case there are two options. ReadLine works with a suffix for the barcode right? Can I define which character shall be the newline interpretation?

Comment: You can't define which character `ReadLine` function terminates at (it will always be a newline character). If you have control of the barcode, ensure it always has a newline character at the end. If you can give me the barcode reader device details like make, model number, etc. I can point you in a more accurate direction for a solution. All barcode readers want you to read properly and usually they have a precise way to interpret the data.

Comment: its a honeywell 1911i and yes i can influence which characters i want to have in front or in the back. Im just not familiar with a "NewLine" character. In the character chart I see "NP Enter" twice and "Enter / Ret" twice, which i figure are the closest of resembling a newline https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1061231/Honeywell-Xenon-1900.html?page=257

Comment: NewLine character depends on the operating system so would be careful when using that. Also since you can control the characters at the front and back, it would be simple to work with that. Tell me are the characters always numbers? or the data can be alphanumeric? also do you need to follow any [barcode standards](https://www.barcodefaq.com/barcoding-for-beginners/)?

Comment: According to the [Honeywell 1911i manual](http://cdn.cnetcontent.com/55/e4/55e4041c-ff64-42a5-8a23-c4d92208d5c2.pdf) on page 2-1 (pg 27) under *Programming the Interface* > *RS232 Serial Port* If you scan this, it should add a suffix of carriage return and line feed (basically a new line character) to the scan. Once you do that it should work with the `ReadLine` method